# input of all column names in dplyr case_when and assign to new column based on condition

Tags: r, dynamic, tidyverse, dplyr

Hello stack overflow community -

In R, I want to generate a new column based on multiple columns in a data frame. I want the new column to assign the column name if a condition is meet for each row. For instance, in the iris dataset below, the new column 'Biggest' either gets 'Sepal.Length' or 'Petal.Length' dependent on condition of size (i.e. Sepal.Length>= 6.1 or Petal.Length< 6.0). This works successfully.

```
data(iris)
irisOne <- subset(iris, Species=="virginica") %>%
  select("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length")

irisOne %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Biggest = 
                  dplyr::case_when(
                    Sepal.Length >= 6.1 ~ "Sepal.Length",
                    Petal.Length <= 6.0 ~ "Petal.Length"
                  ))
```

My question is how would one extend this to be agnostic to column names and use those column names in the new column in the case_when section. My actually dataset has > 50 column names and I don't want to code all of that. I thought it would be something including all_vars but have been unsuccessful in implementing this, see below for my attempt.

```
irisOne %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Biggest = 
                  !!all_vars(.),
                  dplyr::case_when(
                    . >= 6.1 ~ .,
                    . <= 6.0 ~ .
                  ))
```

Comment: How do you know which columns need to be compared with `>= 6.1` and which ones with `<= 6.0`. Do you have a mapping list saved somewhere of these comparisons?

Comment: Good question and I definitely see that would need to be a requirement. In my data, the way I would read the if statement is like so: if column X > 6.1 then assign to new column as X, else if column Y  > 6.1 then assign new column as Y else if column Z > 6.1 then assign as column Z. I see in my example, how it would be necessary to have a mapping list because used two options (>=6.1 or <= 6.0).

Comment: and what happens if two columns have value > 6.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can take help of `max.col` -

```
data$Biggest <- colnames(data)[max.col(data >= 6.1, ties.method = 'first')]
```